# How to get specific child data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have need to access a specific child from node, i have only "available key" of the specific child not complete path.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please take a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the key of the child you're looking for, you can query on that:

```
DatabaseReference schoolsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("School");
Query query = schoolsRef.orderByKey().equalTo("MZ3bW5kLJAQorgnZbYiTaOoWWSG2");

db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String email = userSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Note that you can't use `orderByChild("id")` as explained in my answer 
 here: [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested).

Comment: Thanks bro for suggestion, "dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()" is totally empty

Comment: Yeah, there we a few mistakes in there. Since this is a query, you need a loop over the snapshot.

Comment: Thanks bro, i can do this by using loops, but i am searching a way to do this by without loops.

Comment: There isn't. Since you don't know the parent key, you need to run a query. And query results can (on an API level) always contain multiple children, so you need to loop over them.

Comment: Also note that you never mentioned this goal in your original question. Consider giving a better example of what you're trying to accomplish, what you've already tried, and why that doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience and thanks for excellent explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
DatabaseReference mUserNameReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("School").child("id").child("id");
    mUserNameReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString());
                   //get all the key value like this
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: change both child id according to your ids

Comment: i have only second id but not first

Comment: then you have to get first id before get the values

Comment: first just add the hard code and set both ids and try is it working

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("school").child(firebaseUser.getUid();

db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String email = dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have key for that child but not complete path first get key of parent node in list like below I did.

```
 Arraylist<String> keyList =new Arraylist();
      DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("school").child(firebaseUser.getUid();

        db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = childSnapshot.getKey();

                String value=  childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                keyList.add(key);

            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

now use for loop or foreach loop to check if that node contains available child key.

```
for(String key:keyList){



 DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("school").child(key).orderByChild("id").equal(availableKey);

            db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = childSnapshot.getKey();

                    Object object=  childSnapshot.getValue(Object.class);



                }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });







}
```

hope this will help you..